# I would like to read X , Y coordinate data from a SQLite database table using javascript so that I can use a jquery plug in to plot the points.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sqlite

I am using WAMP with javascript and jquery code shown below. I  would like to read X , Y coordinate data from a SQLite relational database table using javascript so that I can use a jquery plug in to plot the x - y coordinate points. 
  My question is could someone show the complete javascript code to read X , Y coordinate data from a SQLite relational database table? Thanks.

```
--------------------------------------my index.html-----------------------

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>jVectorMap demo</title> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-jvectormap-1.1.1.css"
    type="text/css" media="screen"/>
     <script src="jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery-jvectormap-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="us-aea-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function saturday () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '°C'
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Tokyo',
                    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
                }, {
                    name: 'New York',
                    data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
                }, {
                    name: 'Berlin',
                    data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
                }, {
                    name: 'London',
                    data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
                }]
            });
        };



    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="USA-map" style="width: 1200px; height: 800px"></div>
      <script language="javascript">
        function processOrder() {
         var pluginContainer = $("#USA-map");
            pluginContainer.vectorMap(
           {
               map: 'us_aea_en',
               onRegionOver: function(event, code){
                   pluginContainer.saturday();
               }
           }
         );
      }
       </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>

    <script src="highcharts.js"></script>

    <script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js">
    </script>


    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


    </body>
    </html>
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ---------------------------------my foo.js--------------------------------
    processOrder();
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `My question is could someone show the complete javascript code` Stack Overflow is not a code generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to use client-side JavaScript to access an SQLite database. You'd be better off using a server-side script to extract the data from the database and turn it into JSON, which JavaScript can trivially process.

---

## Example server-side script

You didn't specify any language for the server-side script, so I'll use Python 3 running as a CGI script, as it's pretty simple:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import contextlib
import sqlite3
import json
import sys

with contextlib.closing(sqlite3.connect('coordinates.db')) as database:
    with contextlib.closing(database.cursor()) as cursor:
        cursor.execute('select x, y from coordinates')
        coordinates = []
        for x, y in cursor:
            coordinates.append({'x': x, 'y': y})

print("Content-Type: application/json")
print()
json.dump(coordinates, sys.stdout)
```

It should be pretty easy with other languages, too. In PHP, for example, you'd want to go with PDO and `json_encode`.

---

## Example JavaScript usage

To load and process the result in JavaScript, you should be able to use [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```js
jQuery.get("coordinates.json", function(data) {
    // somehow use data
});
```

If you're using the Python code I provided above, `data` will be an array of objects with `x` and `y` properties. How you choose to use this is up to you; I am unfamiliar with the other libraries you're using.

Comment: @@icktoofay, Please provide with an url that shows the server-side script to extract the data from the database and turn it into JSON. Thanks, Frank (P.S. I accept your answer).

Comment: Please provide with an url that shows the server-side script to extract the data from the database and turn it into JSON. Thanks, Frank (P.S. I accept your answer).

Comment: @Frank: I've added an example server-side Python 3 CGI script that would suffice as a backend. Similar code should work in other languages.

Comment: @@icktoofay, Thank you for your help.May I ask where in your python script I would specify the SQLite Database file name? Thanks, Frank

Comment: Thank you for your help.May I ask where in your python script I would specify the SQLite Database file name? Thanks, Frank

Comment: @Frank: I used `coordinates.db` as a sample file name. That should be all you need to change, supposing the query in there is also correct. (If the query's incorrect, you'll need to change that, too.)

Comment: @@icktoofay, Thank you for your help. May I ask how the server script python file is invoked? Thanks, Frank

Comment: Thank you for your help. May I ask how the server script python file is invoked? Thanks, Frank

Comment: @Frank: See [the section of the Python documentation on installing CGI scripts](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/cgi.html#installing-your-cgi-script-on-a-unix-system).

Comment: @Frank: Alternatively, if the SQLite database is static, you can remove the `print` calls in my script and run it ahead of time as, e.g., `python3 convert.py > coordinates.json`.

Comment: @@icktoofay, Thank you for your help. May I ask how to write the javascript code to process the coordinates.json? Thanks, Frank (by the way how may @'s should I insert before icktoofay?)

Comment: Thank you for your help. May I ask how to write the javascript code to process the coordinates.json? Thanks, Frank (by the way how may @'s should I insert before icktoofay?)

Comment: @Frank: You'll probably want to use [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). If you used the Python script I provided, you'll get an array of objects with `x` and `y` properties, which you can process as your charting library requires. I'm not familiar with Highcharts, so I can't help you further.

Comment: @@icktoofay, Thank you for your help this evening. I have a meeting in Kendall Square, Massachusetts to prepare a demo for. By the way how may @'s should I insert before icktoofay?

Comment: Thank you for your help this evening.By the way how may @'s should I insert before icktoofay?

Comment: @Frank: Since you're commenting on my answer, you don't need to mention my name at all. In all other cases, a single `@` should be sufficient.

Comment: I am very grateful for all you taught me tonight. Thanks,Frank.